# Passing a variable to find -mtime command

Tags: bash, shell

I'm currently trying to write a script that will delete a file after X days using the **find** command.

When using the following command it works and successfully deletes any file that is >10 days old.

```
find /path/to/file/to/delete -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

However, when trying to pass this as a script argument using the following command:

./delete-old-files.sh 10

```
find /path/to/file/to/delete -type f -mtime +$1 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

I am met with this error:

```
find: invalid argument `+' to `-mtime'
```

Is there some way I should be wrapping the variable to ensure it isn't impeding the `-mtime` arguments?

Comment: instead of *'-exec rm -f {}'* you could *'-print -delete'* and for non-initialized var you can use *${var:-default}* like *${1:-0}*

Comment: What is the content of the `$1` argument when it reaches your `find` command? Insert `printf '%q\n' "$1";exit` to the line before the `find` command, and run your script again. It will print the actual content of your `$1` argument.

Comment: Can you show us more details about your script (i.e. show most parts of the script). I have a fuzzy feeling that `$1` is not anymore what you expect it is.

Comment: `delete-old-files(){ find . -type f -mtime +$1 -exec echo rm -f {} \; ; }`  Works for me, so you need to show the entirety of your script

Answer (score 0):

in your script run delete-old-files() with arguments, otherwise *local `$1`* remain empty because it is not the same as *global `$1`* of your script

```
./delete-old-files.sh 10
```

for better understanding in this example *global `$1`* is passed to *local `$2`* as argument. you can see the difference *local `$1`* is path but *global `$1`* is mtime

```
#!/bin/bash

delete-old-files() {
  local folder
  # just some tests to make sure find will run on folder and mtime is set
  [ "$2" ] && [ -e "$1" ] && folder="$(realpath "$1")"
  [ -d "$folder" ] || return 1

  find "$folder" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +$2 -print #-delete
  return $?
}

delete-old-files /path/to/file/to/delete $1 || exit $?
```

---

**improvement**: you can also read from arguments if you don't want to hard code `path`. you could loop over positional parameters, read `mtime` into var and delete everything what is not a valid path
(see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48720056))

call `find` with remaining arguments (will work on non-trivial folder names)

```
# script
find "$@" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +$days -print #-delete
```

run the script (no function) with as many folders as you like

```
./delete-old-files.sh ~/dir1 "path/to/dir 2" 10
```